# New Windows Form opens, loads incompletely and freezes in VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, freeze

I have the following code here which is put in a button click event handler and plots a line graph in a new window in vb.net. I have the data in an array, `columnData(,)`.

```
'GraphWindow is a form where the Chart control is present.
Dim newWindow as New GraphWindow 
Dim i, j, col_length As Double
col_length = eRange.Rows.Count
i = row1
j = 1


'Plotting points in the graph
Do
     newWindow.Chart1.Series(0).Points.AddXY(i, columnData(j, 1))
     i += 1
     j += 1
Loop Until i = row2 + 1 And j = col_length + 1


'showing the new window
newWindow.Show()
```

When this code executes, the window opens but does not load the contents of the window completely. It just freezes and then I'll have to stop debugging altogether. `newWindow.ShowDialog()` also doesn't work. Am I going wrong somewhere?

I should also mention that the code *works perfectly fine for a small range of values* where `columnData(,)` holds about less than 10,000 values.

I have observed that as I go above 10,000 values in `columnData(,)` the loading time of the graph increases by a little bit. I have to plot graphs for 250,000+ values, and *when given 250,000+ values as input the new window pops up and just hangs.* Please help!

Comment: It does hang for a while? Maybe is just doing work. Since this work is synchronous the Form Thread will be blocked until work is done. Have you waited or debuuged and watched if it's working or hanging?

Comment: Add an `Application.DoEvents()` statement inside your loop. But it also sounds like your loop should be executing on a separate thread.

Comment: @RafaGomez When I plot for 250,000+ values it freezes and I waited for more than five minutes, nothing happened. I have debugged it and I can see that the Do Loop finishes executing, which means that the plotting of points is happening, and the window pops up and that's it, I can't even drag the window.

Comment: @DiskCrasher Tried that now, I put the loop in a new Background Worker DoWork event and `newWindow.show()` in a RunWorkerCompleted event handler, but didn't work.

Comment: @silentProgrammer I would try using `async` and `await` statements as shown in the second code example [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/async). Have you confirmed that your loop is even completing? It sounds like it may be infinite.

Comment: @DiskCrasher The code works completely fine for a small range of values, which proves that the loop is indeed completing, and the window wouldn't show if it was an infinite loop. Here the window shows and then freezes. I'll check about `async` and `await` and get back to you. Do you think this is happening because something might be blocking the UI thread? I don't understand how it can work fine for 10,000+ values and then not work for 250,000+ values when the window is made to show only after the graph has been completely plotted. :/

Comment: @silentProgrammer It's possibly a limitation of the Chart1 object, not your code.

Comment: @DiskCrasher I found the glitch, the graph didn't load because of the tooltip in Series in the Chart object. It lagged for a lot of values. I cleared the tooltip property and added a separate event handler with a separate tooltip, and it worked just fine.